# IF condition within WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to know how to use an IF condition within a WHERE clause, I leave the idea in php:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= '2017-08-04' 

IF(date = '2017-08-04' ){
AND hour > '12:00'
}
```

so the idea is that if date equals today's date then add `AND hour > '12:00'`

Comment: yes, you can, find any manual about SQL language and find `case` statement

Comment: yes I read about CASE I tried this but had no luck:
`CASE 
  WHEN date = '2017-08-04' THEN (hour > '12:00')  
 ELSE 0     
END`

Comment: I suppose it should be something like that `select...from...where 1 = (CASE WHEN date = '2017-08-04' THEN when hour > '12:00' then 1 else 0 end when date > '2017-08-04' then 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use basic boolean logic.  The exact translation (ignoring `NULL` values) looks like:

```
WHERE date >= '2017-08-04' AND
      (date <> '2017-08-04' OR hour > '12:00')
```

A more sensible alternative:

```
WHERE date > '2017-08-04' OR
      (date = '2017-08-04' AND hour > '12:00')
```

Comment: tx, that did the job, will accept answer in few minutes

Answer (score 0):

select * from table WHERE date >= '2017-08-04' 
AND hour > '12:00'